# Get Timestamp 00:00:00 Yesterday in bash shell

Tags: shell-script, date

I have a script want to get timestamp in begin yesterday (00:00:00 GMT+0) but cannot excute this script

```
dateto=$(date --date="1 days ago" +"%Y-%m-%d")
datetoj=$(date +%s --date "$dateto 07:00:00")
<Im in GMT+7>
```

How can I get timestamp this case?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you, but it looks like you want to *convert* time between timezones.

Since, afaik, London uses GMT+0, I would do something like this:

```
date --date="TZ=\"Europe/London\" $dateto" +%T
```

This will take your local time from `dateto` and output the time in London, given that the time in `dateto` is your current local time.

Should I be proven wrong, about the London's timezone assumption, there exists other option, that is not recommended, but kept for POSIX compatibility: providing GMT+0 hard-coded:

```
date --date="TZ=\"Etc/GMT+0\" $dateto" +%T
```

And if you want your time in UTC, use `date -u`:

```
date --date="$dateto" -u
```

Comment: With London time there is a 1 hour shift for daylight-savings half of the year, since 1916.

Comment: You save my day. Tks very much